# C++ - MultiSwitch

Tags: c++, switch-statement, arguments

I would like to know if this can be done:

```
switch (header[0])
{
case 'M' || 'm':
    break;
case 'K' || 'k':
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

If this cannot be done, I would like to know if there could be other ways to do it, but not using `if` statements.

Thank you.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to normalize `header[0]` (to uppercase), then only test against `M` and `K`.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted so much? It may be a basic question, but I don't think the `case` behaviour is intuitive enough to make the solution obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost:

```
switch (header[0])
{
case 'M':
case 'm':
  break;
case 'K':
case 'k':
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

Remember that switch labels are "fall-through"—reaching another label does not terminate the switch statement.

Answer (score 5):

```
switch (header[0])
{
case 'M':
case 'm':
    break;
case 'K':
case 'k':
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```